# Is it possible in realm to change the primary key later..?

Tags: android, realm

I set a temporary primary locally and save the object to realm, and later the server assigns a unique key for the object and then I want to update the primary key for the object.

So is it possible to reassign a primary key for the object? And what happens when we reassign a primary key to the object? Will it save the object with the old primary key?

Comment: What realm binding are your referring to? Currently changing primary key is restricted in realm cocoa binding, but not in realm java which might be changed in the future.

Comment: @beeender "android" on line 1 :-)

Comment: yes android.. i am using realm for my android project..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to change the value of a primary key up to Realm 1.2.0.

It is prohibited to change primary key value since Realm 2.0.x.

Comment: Yes I have set a temporary primary key which is a string value of current time, and I use node js server's "shortid" library to generate unique keys, so i may need a good mechanism to replace the entire object and its object links.. thanks for the answer..!! :)

Comment: In that case however there is a way: you can do a schema migration. That way you can change the field that has the `@PrimaryKey` annotation and the underlying index/constraint.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** it is possible to change the primary key of an already stored RealmObject, **only** if the updated primary key does not clash with any existing primary key, otherwise Realm will throw an exception. To actually do this you have to get the RealmObject by querying it and modify manually.

So in your usecase if you can guarantee that the server updated primary keys won't clash with any of your temporary key, it would work without any problem.

However IMO this is not a good thing to do.

Comment: So, no, you can't, cause it create a NEW object. It does NOT modify the current value, you're going to have 2 object (the old one, and the updated one)

Comment: No, it updated the same object, current value, you don't need a copy object, if the updated primaryKey does not clash.

Comment: You wrote: "using copyToRealmOrUpdate will create a new RealmObject since it has a new primaryKey." I think "Will create a new RealmObject" means that you'll end having 2 objects.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I edited the answer, I was referring to the default behaviour of copyToRealmOrUpdate.